# Icon on a Panzoom map - JS

Tags: javascript, html, icons, panzoom

I'd like to place icons on a map (img) that I'm using with [panzoom](https://github.com/timmywil/panzoom)

Here my HTML :

```
<div id="map-body">
<img id="map-img" src="assets/map.jpg">
<i class="fas fa-map-pin icone"></i>
</div>
```

Also my JS :

```
var img = document.getElementById('map-img');

var panzoom = Panzoom(img, {
    maxScale: 8,
    contain: 'outside',
});

img.addEventListener("wheel", panzoom.zoomWithWheel);
```

I want to keep the "outside" property, which allows me to keep the image in my main div, as well as zooming and moving.

I've tried using different, more recent panzooms, but I lose the "outside" property...

Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: Please make sure the whole content of your post is in English, as stackoverflow is an English-only site